# NewRelic NullPointerException

Tags: android, newrelic

I have integrated newRelic with my android app, But i am getting NullPointerException.

```
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404): Caught error while initializing TraceMachine, shutting it down
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at com.newrelic.agent.android.sample.Sampler.stop(Sampler.java:101)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at com.newrelic.agent.android.sample.Sampler.stop(Sampler.java:65)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at com.newrelic.agent.android.sample.Sampler.onTraceComplete(Sampler.java:174)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at com.newrelic.agent.android.tracing.TraceMachine.completeActivityTrace(TraceMachine.java:160)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at com.newrelic.agent.android.tracing.TraceMachine.startTracing(TraceMachine.java:83)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at com.codenterprise.CashbackKorting.Tab.onCreate(Tab.java)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
03-24 10:49:29.609: E/com.newrelic.agent.android(23404):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have checked every step and have latest version of newRelic but still facing this issue.
Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is line number 101 and 65 in `sampler.java`.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: @InnocentKiller sampler.java is some native calss. i can't access its code

Comment: @user3441778, but i think you are getting error over there only.

Comment: I actually figures out that if i removes these lines for push notification than every thing is fine.             ParseObject Object = new ParseObject("AppKey");
    
    TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    devicetoken = tManager.getDeviceId();

    Object.put("user_objectId", "user_"+devicetoken);
    Object.saveInBackground();